# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare twig_without()

Tags: debugging

Getting the below error after I tried to install new modules to D8.

> [error] 32411#32411: *31 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP
>   Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare twig_without() (previously declared in
>   /var/www/html/drupal/modules/drupal-8.7.7/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine:140)
>   in /var/www/html/drupal/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine on line
>   140" while reading response header from upstream, client:

Could someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Unfortunately it's not possible to debug your site from here. The error message is telling you that a function (`twig_without`), has been declared twice, which is not valid in PHP. As `twig_without` is included in Drupal core, you can probably assume this is a bug in one of the modules you've installed, and should report it to the issue queue on drupal.org